# Macro for selecting and arranging shapes horizontally

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to vba, and I am trying to create a macro that can:

1. Clone the latest slide and duplicate the shape similar to the one I put in my first slide. Essentially creating a list of slides that have the same shape with the number of (same)shape increase by one
2. Arrange the shapes in each slide so that they are horizontally arranged next to each other (top aligned, edge to edge)

I'm running into the problem of arranging the shapes. It seems that the window selection is not working. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code

```
Sub AutoGen()

Dim oPresentation As Presentation
Set oPresentation = ActivePresentation
Dim sreDuplicate As ShapeRange
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oSlides As SlideRange
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim aShape As Shape
Dim aSlide As Slide
Dim slideNumber As Integer
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue

Message = "Enter how many you want to create"    ' Set prompt.
Title = "AutoGen"    ' Set title.
Default = "1"    ' Set default.
' Display message, title, and default value.
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
EndLoopValue = CInt(MyValue)

'Create/copy lastest slide and duplicate the shape in the latest slide (first shape index)
For slideNumber = 1 To EndLoopValue

    Set oSlide = oPresentation.Slides(oPresentation.Slides.count)
    oSlide.Copy
    Set oNewSlides = oPresentation.Slides.Paste()
    Set oSlide = oNewSlides(1)
    Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(1)
    Set sreDuplicate = oShape.Duplicate()
    
Next slideNumber
'Loop Through each selected Shape (align with first selected)
For Each aSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    
    'Count How Many Shapes Are Selected
    count = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.count
    
    'Loop Through each selected Shape (align with first selected)
    For curix = 1 To count
      If curix = 1 Then
        Set shp = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        topy = shp.Top
        lastx = shp.Left + shp.Width
      Else
        Set shp = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange(curix)
        'Align Top
        shp.Top = topy
        'Align Center (Vertical Center)
        shp.Left = lastx
        lastx = shp.Left + shp.Width
      End If
    Next curix
    
Next aSlide
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a For loop that loops through all slides, but then inside that you use Windows(1).Selection. A selection can exist on only one slide, not on a collection of them.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Which code should I use to select all the shape on the current slide when the For loop is looping through the slides? or change my selection to match the slide the For loop is currently on?

Comment: You should avoid using the selection object unless you need to perform an action on a previously selected object. Otherwise, you should use ranges for everything. The objective of you code is not clear. If you copy the last selected slide, then all its shapes will get copied with it. I don't understand why you have the second step to copy the shapes again.